# Where does this equation for $n\binom{\binom{n-1}{2}}{m}$ come from?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I'm reading a proof and am having trouble seeing why the following two lines are true:

\begin{align*}
n\frac{\binom{\binom{n-1}{2}}{m} }{ \binom{\binom{n}{2}}{m}}
&= n \left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)^m \prod_{i=1}^{m-1} \left(1 - \frac{4i}{n(n-1)(n-2)-2i(n-2)} \right) \\
&= n \left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)^m \left( 1+ O\left(\frac{(\log n)^2}{n}\right) \right)
\end{align*}

I have tried breaking down the initial binomial term, but it gets messy very quickly. Can someone shed some light here?

Edit: I forgot to add what is probably a relevant fact: here $m=\frac{1}{2}n(\log n+w(n))$ and $w(n)=o(\log n)$.

Comment: You're right, I forgot part of the left hand side. I fixed it now.

Comment: A hint that may help: $C(n,k) = \prod_{i=1}^{k}(\frac{n+1-i}{i})$ - Source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first part:

> The following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{N}{m}&=\frac{N(N-1)\cdots(N-m+1)}{m!}\\
> &=\frac{N^m}{m!}\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{m -1}{N}\right)\\
> &=\frac{N^m}{m!}\prod_{i=1}^{m-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{N}\right)
> \end{align*}

With $N=\binom{n-1}{2}$, resp. $\binom{n}{2}$ we obtain

> \begin{align*}
> &\binom{\binom{n-1}{2}}{m}\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{m}^{-1}\\
> &\quad=\left(\frac{1}{m!}\binom{n-1}{2}^m\prod_{i=1}^{m-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{\binom{n-1}{2}}\right)\right)
> \left(m!\binom{n}{2}^{-m}\prod_{i=1}^{m-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{\binom{n}{2}}\right)^{-1}\right)\tag{1}\\
> &\quad=\left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)^m\prod_{i=1}^{m-1}\left(1-\frac{2i}{(n-1)(n-2)}\right)
> \left(1-\frac{2i}{n(n-1)}\right)^{-1}\\
> &\quad=\left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)^m\prod_{i=1}^{m-1}
> \left(\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)-2ni}{n(n-1)(n-2)}\right)\left(\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)-2i(n-2)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}\right)^{-1}\\
> &\quad=\left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)^m\prod_{i=1}^{m-1}
> \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)-2ni}{n(n-1)(n-2)-2i(n-2)}\\
> &\quad=\left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)^m\prod_{i=1}^{m-1}
> \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)-2i(n-2)-4i}{n(n-1)(n-2)-2i(n-2)}\\
> &\quad=\left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)^m\prod_{i=1}^{m-1}
> \left(1-\frac{4i}{n(n-1)(n-2)-2i(n-2)}\right)\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the identity from above for both binomial coefficients.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to follow that. But I still don't see where the big-oh comes in in my second equation of the original post. Also, is this some sort of standard result that is used frequently?

Comment: @Fequish: At the time I'm also not sure how to derive the second equation. I don't think this is a standard result. But, I'm rather thinking it's some sort of routine calculation. Where does this example come from?

Comment: By the way, I added some relevant hypothesis that you may have missed. It comes from a book on random graphs.